# DocumentDB stored procedure error

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-cosmosdb

Hello i am need to use powershell with DocumentDB. My code here

```
$url = "https://**********.documents.azure.com:443/"
$key = "*****************************"

$client = [Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient]::new([uri]$url,$key)

$db_list = $client.ReadDatabaseFeedAsync().Result

$coll_list = $client.ReadDocumentCollectionFeedAsync($db_list.CollectionsLink).Result
```

there we have collection, all good,
now we create procedure

```
$proc = [Microsoft.Azure.Documents.StoredProcedure]::new()
$proc.id = 'hello_world'
$proc.body = 'function hello_world() {
            var context = getContext();
            var response = context.getResponse();

            response.setBody("Hello, World");
    }'

$procedure = $client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync($coll_list.SelfLink,$proc)
```

Procedure sucessfully created and in $procedure.Result.Resource.Selflink we have link : dbs/ONIYAA==/colls/ONIYAI9WJgA=/sprocs/ONIYAI9WJgAHAAAAAAAAgA==/

now we can try to execute procedure and we always have error

```
$client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync($procedure.Result.Resource.Selflink)
```

Error log in ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync:

```
ErrorRecord                 : Unable to find an overload for "ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync" and a number of arguments: "2".
StackTrace                  :    в CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , String 
                              )
                                 в System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet
                              ](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
                                 в System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`4.
                              Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                                 в System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyI
                              nstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
WasThrownFromThrowStatement : False
Message                     : Unable to find an overload for "ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync" and a number of arguments: "2".
Data                        : {System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.InterpretedFrameInfo}
InnerException              : 
TargetSite                  : System.Object CallSite.Target(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closu
                              re, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite, System.Object, System
                              .Object, System.String)
HelpLink                    : 
Source                      : Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
HResult                     : -2146233087
```

Why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with powershell use of async .NET packages, so I only have  guesses, but could it be that that your CreateStoredProcedure call hasn't finished and you are sending in null as $procedure when you call ExecuteStoredProcedure? You could confirm this by printing out $procedure in line, although it sounds like you may have already done that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you will need to pass in two parameters to `$client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync()`. The first parameter is a link to the stored procedure, and the second is an array of parameters to be pass in to the stored procedure itself.

Here is the corresponding C# code:

```c#
await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<bool>("/dbs/db_rid/colls/col_rid/sprocs/sproc_rid/", 
    new Player { id="1", name="joe" } , 
    new Player { id="2", name="john" } 
);
```